# Reload MainViewController when PopViewController dismissed

Tags: swift, core-data, reload, uipopovercontroller

I have a main view controller and pop up controller.Please refer screen shots.

[image: Main view controller]

[image: POPUP view controller]

Code :

```
             @IBAction func show(sender: AnyObject) {

    var popView = popupviewcontroller(nibName:"popview",bundle:nil)
    var popController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: popView)

    popController.popoverContentSize = CGSize(width: 450, height: 450)
  popController.presentPopoverFromRect(sender.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Down, animated: true)
}
```

For the popupViewcontoller i used .xib.

When press save button data saved to core data.

Lets come to my problem, in my mainViewController i fetched data and fill them in dynamically created lables.That occurred when view load.I want to reload mainViewController when close button form popViewController pressed.

I tried within the close button my code are here, i just tried to reload the mainVc :

```
         var mainVC = mainviewcontroller()         
    @IBAction func close(sender: AnyObject) {
 self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
       //mainVc.viewDidLoad()
     mainVC.reloadInputViews()
   }
```

Does not give output.
Conclusion : I want a way to refresh view controller from another view in swift.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please tell me why down votes.Then only i can improve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using UITableView only we can reload the data!,So we have to use table view custom cell textfield or Label. Now we can able to reload our custom textfield data.

Answer (score 0):

Does your main ViewController use a `UITableView`?

You can use `viewWillAppear` and get the data again and use `tableView.reloadData()` to reload the data.

EDIT:

with `var mainVC = mainviewcontroller()` you're just making a new instance of your MainViewController. If you want to use `reloadInputViews()`, you can put it in `viewWillLoad`.

Comment: No i don't have any tableview, i used some lables.So i want to reload main VC when pop view closed

Comment: then in `viewWillAppear` you can put `label.text = data` in your MainViewController **after** you've updated your data

Answer (score 0):

You should use protocol for it. You can read more about protocols here `https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html`

You can make protocol in PopViewController

`protocol PopViewControllerProtocol {
    static var valuesChanged()
}`

Later you should implement this protocol in MainViewController and refresh data.

Example:

File UIPopoverController.swift

```
protocol UIPopoverControllerDelegate{
    func valuesChanged(changedValue:String)
}

class UIPopoverController: UIViewController {

var delegate: UIPopoverControllerDelegate! = nil
@IBAction func close(sender: AnyObject) {
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   //mainVc.viewDidLoad()
 mainVC.valuesChanged("some value")
}}
```

File MainViewController.swift

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverControllerDelegate       
{
   func valuesChanged(changedValue:String) {
     //this will be called when popuviewcontroller call valueschanged on delegate object
   }

     @IBAction func show(sender: AnyObject) {

var popView = popupviewcontroller(nibName:"popview",bundle:nil)
var popController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: popView)
popController.delegate = self;
popController.popoverContentSize = CGSize(width: 450, height: 450)
popController.presentPopoverFromRect(sender.frame, inView: self.view,      permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Down, animated: true)
 }
}
```

Comment: where i can make protocol within the class or globally.And static var valuesChanged() is like an function why it is used.If you give more details means will be helpful

Comment: Thanks.class MainViewController: UIViewController, PopUPViewControllerDelegate      in this line did you meant UIPopoverControllerDelegate instead of PopUPViewControllerDelegate

Comment: ok.The data pass between view controller.But the view did not reload,thats only i want.i have a question why you passed some value to view controller just for checking right.

Comment: Just for example, if you don't need it, remove this from method

Answer (score 0):

With God Grace  i found a solution that is , just create a Global variable

```
             Var fetchedArray = Nsarray()
```

Then Write the following code in the popovoer controller save button

```
     func save(){
          // Write codes for saving data 

           let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Enitity name")

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        let   Total   = try? context.executeFetchRequest(request)



        if let wrapResults = Total {

            fetchedArray = wrapResults

        }


             }
```

Then fill the Labels by using fetchedArray.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2, try

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle 
viewDidLoad()
return.None
```

Works for me